# how to find the root of a website when it's not the domain?

Tags: javascript, url

I'm working on a version switcher for a documentation builder. The idea is to redirect the user to the root of the documentation website if the page is not existing in prior version.

For example, this page: https://pydata-sphinx-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/index.html does not exist in v0.9 so if the user click on v0.9 he should be redirected to https://pydata-sphinx-theme.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.0/.

The main difficulty is that depending where the documentation is build (locally, or in a 3rd party tool like RDT) the root is not built the same way. I tried the following code:

```js
/**
 * Check if the corresponding url is absolute and make a absolute path from root if necessary
 *
 * @param {string} url the url to check
 */
function makeAbsoluteUrl(url) {
  // Regular expression pattern to match relative URLs
  const pattern = /^(?!(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/)/i;
  const base_url = window.location.origin;
  url = pattern.test(url) ? base_url + "/" + url : url;

  return url;
}
```

Problem is that in the RDT build the root of the website is not the `origin`. Is there a way to guess it from the page ?

EDIT:

To help people uderstand the problem here is a real life example. I build the documentation in a PR using RDT, the website first accessible file is "https://pydata-sphinx-theme--1344.org.readthedocs.build/en/1344/". I should get the "en/1344/" in the return of my function instead of "https://pydata-sphinx-theme--1344.org.readthedocs.build".

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to understand what actual problem you are trying to solve here. Can you please give an example of what the URL in the other scenario would look like?

Comment: If you set your [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) HTML tag correctly, this should all be automatic.

Comment: This is build with Sphinx, I don't build the html myself, I have 0 control on the website tags but let me check if it already exist in the base template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers solved my problem but cannot be generalized to any website, it's mostly solving issues for automatic builder and CD/CI tools. Specific tuning will be needed for more general purpose.

On the specific case of ReadTheDocs, I realized the  https://pydata-sphinx-theme.readthedocs.io link was actually redirecting automatically to  https://pydata-sphinx-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. Same for the PR build were https://pydata-sphinx-theme--1344.org.readthedocs.build redirect to https://pydata-sphinx-theme--1344.org.readthedocs.build/en/1344/.

So I used the fetch API to get the redirection url:

```js
/**
 * Check if the corresponding url is absolute and make a absolute path from root if necessary
 *
 * @param {string} url the url to check
 */
function makeAbsoluteUrl(url) {
  // Regular expression pattern to match relative URLs
  const pattern = /^(?!(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/)/i;
  const base_url = fetch(window.location.origin, {method: "HEAD"}).then(
    (res) => {return res.url;}
  );
  url = pattern.test(url) ? base_url + "/" + url : url;

  return url;
}
```